# Network/Wifi priority setting on Mac 10.13

Tags: wifi

I am using Mac 10.13, and I arranged my networks in the following order:
[image]

May I know which is the computer supposed to connect to if both AndroidAP and SINGTEL-9A62 are available to connect? I was expecting SINGTEL-9A62, because I thought the networks are arranged from highest to lowest priority. Am I correct? It seems that AndroidAP is always connected to, rather than SINGTEL-9A62 though, if the computer has the choice.

If this doesn't seem to be correct, how do I fix this?